# Still getting segmentation fault after calling mprotect in self-modifying assembly code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls, self-modifying

I'm trying to learn some stack overflow techniques and use shellcode in them.
I was able to successfully use some basic shellcodes. Then I started working on using `exeve` in assembly and invoke `ls -l` with that, again successful.
Now I am trying to use relative addressing and get rid of null values in my code. Because of that I tried a simple self-modifying code. I know code segment is read-only so I tried calling `mprotect` to make it writable. My code still doesn't work and I get segmentation fault at `movb %al, 0x7(%esi)`. I really appreciate it if someone could give me some insight into the thing that is wrong in my code.

```
.text
.globl _start

_start:
  jmp StartPoint

  execvecall:
  popl %esi    # the address of string

  #calling mprotect to make the memory writable
  movl $0x7d, %eax
  movl %esi, %ebx
  movl $0x20, %ecx
  movl $7, %edx
  int $0x80

  xorl %eax, %eax

  movb %al, 0x7(%esi)  #putting zero for at the end of /bin/ls
  movb %al, 0xa(%esi)  #putting another zero at the end of -l

  #this part forms an array ending with for the second parameter of execve
  movl %esi, 0xb(%esi)
  movl %esi, %ebx
  addl $8, %ebx
  movl %ebx, 0xf(%esi)
  movl %eax, 0x13(%esi)

  movl %esi, %ebx
  leal 0xb(%esi), %ecx
  leal 0x13(%esi), %edx

  movb $11, %al
  int $0x80

StartPoint:
  call execvecall
SomeVarHere:
  .ascii "/bin/ls0-l0111122223333"
```

Comment: I suggest checking the return value.

Comment: I've checked and it isn't -1.

Comment: I executed your code and gdb tells me its returning `-22` (a.k.a `EINVAL` on my machine).

Comment: Use `strace` to see what your code does, if you aren't running it under gdb.  It saves a lot of debug-prints in C code that you write to try out some system calls, too.

Comment: Some systems may disallow having write and execute permissions at the same time, e.g: PaX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaX#Restricted_mprotect.28.29 , OpenBSD W^X https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX , ... See also http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/selinux-mem.html for Ulrich Drepper's recommended way of doing this under SELinux.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. They were really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man mprotect` says:

> The implementation may require that `addr` be a multiple of the page size as returned by `sysconf()`.

This is apparently the case on your machine. Assuming you have 4 KiB pages (as on x86, no PSE), you can round the address down by executing

```
and $0xfffff000, %ebx
```

after

```
movl %esi, %ebx
```

when preparing to call `mprotect`.

Note that calling `mprotect` changes the protection for the **whole page.**

Comment: Thanks man, I thought it would be the problem but I don't remember why I didn't at least try it!!! :-(